# How to change color of MetroTabItem

Tags: mahapps.metro

I have `MetroTabControl`, with items added programmatically (I'm using Prism) but I don't know how to change color of `TabItem` header.

How can I do that? I'm new to Mahapps.Metro, where should I start to learn in customization?

Answer (score 0):

### Styles - MahApps.Metro

1. Take a look here : [Mahapps Styles](http://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html)
2. You can override the default Style of the MetroTabItem.

   - Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY0RSBipZhw) of how to accomplish style inheritance in WPF.
   - Here is the MetroTabItem style : [MetroTabItem.xaml](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/336f7dfc4bda2d0eba8aa270737ca3c11d45128c/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Themes/MetroTabItem.xaml)

I would suggest you to learn how to create custom style in mahapps 
(The first point).